# Doubt on piecewise function

Tags: functions, absolute-value, piecewise-continuity

Suppose we have a function given by:

$f(x)= \begin{cases}
x & x < 0\\
x+1 & x \ge 0
\end{cases}$

Then

$f(|x|)= \begin{cases}
|x| & x < 0 \\
|x|+1 & x \ge 0\end{cases}$

Or

$f(|x|)= \begin{cases}
|x| & |x|<0\\
|x|+1 & |x|\ge0
\end{cases}$

I.e.
$f(|x|)= |x|+1$ as $|x|$ is not $<0$.

Please tell me which one is correct and why?

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Just to make sure I understand the question: you are given a piecewise-defined function $f(x)$, and you are asked to find a formula for $f(|x|)$?  As of your last edit, both of your options for the answer look the same to me.

Comment: Yes that's my question. In that the main doubt is that when we apply mod to the function then should apply it to the conditions as well i.e. x<0 becomes |x|<0. Why? @Matthew Leingang

Answer (score 1):

For every $x\in \mathbb R$, we have $$|x|\geq 0$$

Hence, by very definition of $f$, we must have $$f(|x|)=|x|+1$$
for every $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry you are correct I have corrected the question.

Comment: So when we apply mod to the function it affects the  conditions as well I.e. x<0 becomes |x|<0. Is that right? Could you explain why we do this i.e. apply mod to condition as well. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this would be clearer if we chose to use another letter for the definition of $f$. The function $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ by sending a number $z\in \mathbb R$ on $z$ is it is negative, on $z+1$ if it is non-negative. Here, we apply the function $f$ to the number $|x|$. The operation we are doing is replacing $z$ with $|x|$. Because $|x|$ is a non-negative number, we know that it will be sent to $|x|+1$ via the function $f$.

Comment: Okay. Nice I really liked your explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What would happen if instead of zero the condition was x<2 and x>=2 for the two parts of the function respectively? That is a non-zero number in the given conditions

Comment: @DhruvDeshmukh Then, the function would send $|x|$ to $|x|$ whenever $|x|<2$ and to $|x|+1$ whenever $|x|\geq 2$. One easily sees that $|x|<2 \Leftrightarrow x\in ]-2,2[$, and also that $|x|\geq 2 \Leftrightarrow x\in ]-\infty ,-2]\cup [2,\infty [$.

Comment: Okay got it thanks.